# These [diagrams] are confusing

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

At the moment I started to type this question there were 117 questions with the [diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) tag. 13 of them were about the *diagrams* Haskell library; in these, I have just replaced the tag with [haskell-diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-diagrams). In 40 others there also is [uml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uml), and so [diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) can presumably be removed from them. I have no clue about the 64 remaining questions, but if nothing else they might be at least assimilated into the significantly bigger mess of the [diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diagram) tag (1172 questions, 356 of them also having [uml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uml)).

Comment: *assimilated ... bigger mess* Oh my ...

Comment: @rene Well, we can also discuss what is to be done (if anything) with [tag:diagram]. Given that things like [tag:charts] and [tag:plot] seem to be considered legitimate tags, I guess there is no reason for burninating [tag:diagram] in its generic meaning of "drawing which is a schematic representation". Any other meanings might conceivably be handled according to the accompanying tags.

Comment: Besides the 356 diagram question also tagged uml there are 100 tagged with class. If that is what I think it is, [tag:diagram] is up for burninating. But I agree that we can first handle this one.